# WhatsApp cloud template not allowing line break in variable text

Tags: cloud, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a WhatsApp message using cloud API.

I created a template in WhatsApp cloud for simple text i.e. without header and footer, I added only body with one parameter like:

> hi {{1}}
>
> .. ..

This template is valid and able to send message without line break in message i.e. (in variable part from postman)

My payload from postman is:

```
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"recipient_type": "individual",
"to": "{{message_to}}",
"type": "template",
"template": {
"name": "simple_text_only",
"language": {
  "code": "en_US"
},
"components": [
  {
      "type" : "body",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "HIIIIII\nok"
        },
      ]
  }
]
```

}
}

Response is

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "Param text cannot have new-line/tab characters or more than 4 consecutive spaces"
        },
        "error_subcode": 2494073,
        "fbtrace_id": "Av68Tbsx7_vCLzDzf7RUR"
    }
}
```

If I send message without <kbd>\n</kbd> then it is sending, but I want to send the message in next line like:

> 1 some text
> 2 some text

Comment: Can you show URL?

Comment: URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{{numberid}}/messages
POST Method

Comment: I try it but I don't know `Recipient-WA-ID` and `Phone-Number-ID` 
URL POST `https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages`
And Body `"to": "{{Recipient-WA-ID}}"`, 
Error message. "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '100089598486524' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.

Comment: I am confusing between App and Messenger's Page. Each has own ID, App ID and Page ID. How to related API and my previous question?

Answer (score 2):

try with

`{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "recipient_type": "individual", "to": "{{message_to}}", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "simple_text_only", "language": { "code": "en_US" }, "components": [ { "type" : "body", "parameters": [ { "type": "text", "text": "HIIIIII\\nok" }, ] } ] } }`

In this case you replace `\n` with `\\n`